# D state process kill

Tags: process, kill

There is a D state process (stuck) which is not killed even by `kill -9`.
I see PPID is systemd.

```
root       1863      1     0        **Ds**    /usr/sbin/smartd -n

root          1      0     0        **Ss**    /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 23
```

How can I kill the D state process without a node hard reboot?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I kill the D state process without a node hard reboot?

You can't (that's why it's called *uninterruptible* sleep), but they will usually die on their own once they wake up from whatever is keeping them blocked. Otherwise, if the process is waiting for some resource that will never become available, or possibly if there is a kernel bug, there is nothing you can do from userspace.